# Adobe Flash Builder read a text file and sort it by substring

Tags: apache-flex, text, substring, flash-builder

In my Adobe Flash Builder project, I want to read a text file line-by-line, and get the number of each category (according to the value of a substring).

This my text file (MyTest.txt):

```
1988031,PROJECT,001.pdf,09012d9f80007111,09012d9f80007120
1988033,TEST,033.pdf,09012d9f80007921,09012d9f80007930
1988035,PROJECT,035.pdf,09012d9f80008db1,09012d9f80008dc0
1988036,PROJECT,036.pdf,09012d9f80008db2,09012d9f80008dc1
```

What I want to get:

1. Substring 0 - Substring 4 for each line
2. Number of lines which contains "PROJECT"

I found some solution for Adobe AIR, but I failed to find an answer for Flash.

I am stuck on how to process the text file.

**How can get the result I want?**

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're asking.  Are you stuck with reading in the file in Flash (i.e. no AIR APIs), or are you stuck with processing the data you have in that file?  Or something else?  Please update your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.split()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html) method to split the lines at commas.

(If you have commas surrounded by white space - use regexes instead of split).

Put split-results into objects and store them into an [ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html).

Then sort the ArrayCollection with [spark.collections.Sort](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf668d2-7ff2.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b66).